# Need Help to Reduce React App Build Size (330MB)

Tags: reactjs, optimization, build

I've been facing a significant issue with the build size of my React app. Currently, the build size is a staggering 330MB, which is obviously not optimal.I also noticed, in folder the number of JS chunks are more than 500 in which few are size of 14 to 20 mb. I am already using lazy loading in my Route file. I believe this is primarily due to the large number of dependencies my project utilizes. Here's the list of dependencies from my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.x",
    "@date-io/dayjs": "1.x",
    "@draft-js-plugins/editor": "^4.1.3",
    "@draft-js-plugins/inline-toolbar": "^4.1.6",
    "@dschoon/react-waves": "^4.0.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.1",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^28.2.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "^28.2.1",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "chart": "^0.1.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.8.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.9.5",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.9",
    "gridjs-react": "^3.4.0",
    "highcharts": "^8.2.2",
    "highcharts-3d": "^0.1.7",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.0.0",
    "joi-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.1.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.13",
    "jszip": "^3.5.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0",
    "kml-parse": "^0.0.2",
    "kmljs": "^0.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.12.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "material-table": "^1.69.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "parse-kml": "^1.0.1",
    "query-string": "^6.13.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.17.0",
    "react-audio-spectrum": "^0.1.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
    "react-avatar-edit": "^0.9.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.2.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-csv-reader": "^3.1.2",
    "react-detect-offline": "^2.4.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
    "react-file-reader": "^1.1.4",
    "react-html-table-to-excel": "^2.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.0.8",
    "react-images-viewer": "^1.6.2",
    "react-json-to-csv": "^1.0.4",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.14",
    "react-mapbox-gl": "^5.1.1",
    "react-navigator-online": "^1.0.7",
    "react-pivottable": "^0.11.0",
    "react-player": "^2.7.2",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.5.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.22",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-select": "^5.4.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.9",
    "react-toastify": "8.2",
    "react-viewer": "^3.2.2",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "react-wavy-audio": "^1.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.4",
    "string_decoder": "^1.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "sunburst": "^2.0.0",
    "survey-analytics": "^1.8.18",
    "survey-creator": "^1.9.4",
    "survey-pdf": "^1.8.22",
    "survey-react": "^1.9.4",
    "surveyjs-widgets": "^1.9.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "uuid-v4": "^0.1.0",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12",
    "wavesurfer": "^1.3.4",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^6.0.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.4",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
  },
```

I'm looking for advice and solutions on how to effectively reduce the build size of my React app.

thank you in advance for your help and expertise!

I try using lazy loading in my Route file

Comment: You are using way too many packages, list down the ones that you can replicate on your own and remove them. Try using more of your own implementation rather than using that many packages. Also try to use suspense and lazy loading (code splitting)  in your components to further minimize your initial bundle size.

Comment: these packages are from the day first. but when I add new pages to my application, my build size increases in MBs. which should not be.

Comment: Of course the size would increase cause whenever a new page is added and when the packages are imported into it, it will increase the bundle size as all those packages will be imported for that page as well.